Convergence in Mean Implies Convergence in Measure
I am self-stuying measure theory. There is this proposition:

Proposition$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$ belong to $\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{R})$. If $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in mean, then $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in measure.

The proof says it is an immediate consequence of the inequality
\begin{align}
\mu(\{x\in X:|f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon\})\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int|f_n-f|d\mu.
\end{align}
While I have no problem understanding this inequality, I do feel confused by the existence of the limit. The assumption that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in mean implies the limit of the right-hand-side exists and is equal to $0$. However, why does the limit of the left-hand-side always exist? Could someone please help me out? Thank you very much!

The left hand side is $\geq 0$. Apply the squeeze theorem.
